# AJV if-then-else conditional type based on enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, ajv

I've searched examples of using `if-then-else` in AJV schemas but haven't found a specific case where the property type and required list change based on the value of another property.

#### Case:

I need to upgrade `userSchema` so that if property `role` = `superuser`, then `customer_id` is both nullable and not required.

```
const userSchema: Schema<UserItem> = {
  $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  type: 'object',
  required: ['id', 'email', 'customer_id'],
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'uuid'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'email'
    },
    customer_id: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'uuid'
    },
    role: {
      anyOf: [
        { type: 'null' },
        { enum: Object.values(UserRole) }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried...

```
const userSchemaNullableCustomerId: Schema<UserItem> = {
  ...userSchema,
  if: {
    properties: {
      role: { const: UserRole.Superuser }
    }
  },
  then: {
    properties: {
      customer_id: {
        anyOf: [
          { type: 'null' },
          { type: 'string', format: 'uuid' }
        ]
      }
    },
    not: {
      required: ['customer_id']
    }
  }
}
```

but it still complains that `data.customer_id should be string`. How can this be solved?

The following should be true:

```
// Valid
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "superuser",
    "customer_id": null
},
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "superuser"
},
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "null",
    "customer_id": 'some-uuid...'
},
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "user",
    "customer_id": 'some-uuid...'
}

// Invalid
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "user",
    "customer_id": null
},
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "user"
},
{
    "id": "id",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "role": "superuser",
    "customer_id": 'nonUuidString'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, I discovered the trick is that the `customer_id` property has to be initialized as empty and the `role` property requires a dependency check.

```
...
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'uuid'
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'email'
    }
    customer_id: {},
    role: {
      anyOf: [
        { type: 'null' },
        { enum: Object.values(UserRole) }
      ]
    }
  },
  if: {
    dependencies: { role: ['role'] },
    properties: { role: { const: UserRole.Superuser } }
  },
  then: {
    properties: { customer_id: { anyOf: [{ type: 'null' }, { type: 'string', format: 'uuid' }] } }
  },
  else: {
    properties: { customer_id: { type: 'string', format: 'uuid' } }
  }
```